# Excel formula to return the value that is not equal to "x"

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

i have 2 columns and 10 rows. the first column has data in it (1a,2a,3a ... 1b,2b,3b...) the second column has a true or false value. i only have 1 true value and all the rest will be false when changing data.

i want whenever a cell is true to show the value of the true cell in a different cell.

the "TRUE" value will be variable in the column.

Comment: Are you searching for a logic?

Comment: Sounds like you're using cells as radiobuttons?

Comment: no not really i just want the first column data that is true to show in another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a "left lookup", i.e. to make this work without swapping columns, you can use `INDEX/MATCH` like this

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,B:B,0))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly

```
=IF(B1=TRUE,A1,"")
```

Add this formula to cell C1 and drag down.

[image]

Comment: ok this is what needed but 1 problem i want 1 cell with value not all the "C" cells. in other words only c1 to show the answer of all the lists.

Comment: Oh ok. I misunderstood your question. So go with vlookup. :)